# How to calculate the F1-Score for a NLP research?

Tags: self-study, predictive-models, text-mining

I have conducted a research about extracting words from a sentence (on natural language processing [(NLP)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural_language_processing)). I would like to know the best way to compute the [F1 score](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/F1_score) for this research. I have categorized the data as follows,

`Total number of words identified by the machine = 9
Total number of words identified by the human = 8
Instances when the words identified were same for both = 5
Words missed by the machine = 1
Words missed by the human = 0`

How do I use this data in order to calculate the F1 score?